# What are the Best way to learn python for non IT person

Tags: python, machine-learning

As a mechanical engineer how I start to learn python and what I need to learn in python For machine learning in mechanical field

Can anyone Suggest best

Comment: There is no way to produce satisfactory answer without knowing more about your backgroud. This beind said, I liked this one: www.amazon.com/Hands-Machine-Learning-Scikit-Learn-TensorFlow/dp/1492032646/

Comment: If you approach the problem as "I want to learn Python but not be a programmer" then you're doomed to fail. By learning Python, you are becoming a programmer. I've met lots of people who could write code but didn't consider themselves "coders", and there's not one of them I would trust to write a software project of any scale. If you truly want to learn Python, then do it the same way everyone else does. There's no "diet Python for engineers", at least not one that's worth anything. There's just "Python", the same one for everybody.

Comment: The tag wiki has all the info need: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are plenty of the free courses on YouTube. Personally, I am not in the machine learning field.
However, to get started in Python, I would suggest the following Python video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw

This is the same video I used when I first got started in Python.

Once you have the basics down, I would suggest you do some beginner projects just to brush up on the skills you have learned. Some of the ones I recommend for total beginners are programs like Tic-Tac-Toe, Hangman, and Random code generators, or even a program that takes a string and turns it into a simple code (like making every letter "a" into "b" and "b" into "c"). Needless to say, there are many, many simple beginner projects. Do a couple of these (around 3-4). This will get you used to Python (remember, you are just scratching the surface).

Next, I would suggest you take a dive into `numpy` and `pandas` modules in Python. These two modules are very important for handling data (and that is critical for machine learning). I am not proficient in `numpy` or `pandas`, but I did look into them at one point. For `numpy`, I watched the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUT1VHiLmmI
and for `pandas` I watched videos by the YouTube channel named Corey Schafer that were about `pandas`.

Now, if you do not have knowledge of the math behind machine learning, you can one of two choices. Some of the machine learning tutorials I am suggesting will allow you to make progress in learning machine learning, but you will definitely not understand the underlying concepts (you will not know what each line of code does, what each block of code is meant to be, but you will not understand the why). You can choose to skip this next step, but it is important to know that it is critical for success to understand the underlying mechanisms of something rather than just the surface (as with everything else). So, I would strongly suggest you look into machine learning courses that simply teach theory rather than practice as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwIo3gDZCVQ

**It is important for me to point out that these resources more than likely will not be enough, as you watch these videos, you will end up having questions that they may not go over, so you will have to do a little bit of research on the internet yourself as well**

After you get those down, you can then actually look into Machine Learning with Python.

I believe there are two main ways you can practice Machine Learning: TensorFlow and PyTorch. I am not aware between the primary differences between the two, but I do know that they are quite popular and have plenty of documentation.
Again, same technique as before. Go on YouTube, and look into courses about Machine Learning, here are a few:

A very, very, long tutorial (~25 hrs) in PyTorch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_xro1bcAuA

Shorter tutorial in PyTorch (~5hrs): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c36lUUr864M

A 2-part TensorFlow Course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpCFfeUEGs8 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUKz4125WNI&t=0s

**Also, I would like to add that along with PyTorch and TensorFlow, there is also Keras, but I believe it may not be as popular and/or well-documented as the other two**

**Also, these are just my suggestions for you to get started from the little knowledge I have about machine learning.
The common thing with beginning something, is that no matter what it is, it generally starts with scratching the surface of the basics, and just sitting down and watching tutorials for long hours until you get the hang of it**